# C, Why can't I declare pointer and initialize it?

Tags: c, pointers

Well, I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    const char *usuario= NULL;
    while(*envp)
    {
        char *str = *envp++;
        //if(strcmp(str,"USERNAME")==0)
        if(str[0] == 'U' && str[1] == 'S' && str[2]=='E' && str[3]=='R' && str[4] == 'N')
        {
            usuario = str;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(usuario != NULL)
    {
        printf("Hola, bienvenido al programa %s",usuario);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And my question is why can't I declare the variable outside the while and initialize it inside?

```
char *str;
const char *usuario= NULL;
while(*envp)
{
    *str = *envp++;
    if(`...
```

The compiler says: **warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast**

Comment: Aside: you should check the environment string is long enough before testing `if(str[0] == 'U' && ... && str[4] == 'N')`. It should be at least length 5, or the indexing breaks.

Comment: Thank you my friend, there are two things I could not understand lol.

First, how did you get my code to go into a complete picture?
I put the code between these characters "` `" but it did not work out that way.

And the other is what do you mean "you should check the environment string is long enough before testing"? Because I'm supposed to be reading about the environment variables, and there's always the variable USERNAME. I did not quite understand what you meant by that.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "_I'm new to this forum_" Stack Overflow isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Is the same, I quote from wikipedia "Un foro de Internet es un sitio de discusión online asincrónico donde las personas publican mensajes alrededor de un tema, creando de esta forma un hilo de conversación jerarquico (thread en inglés)"

:)

Comment: Btw, `*str = *envp++;` is not an initialization. It's an assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

The problem is that you're not assigning to your pointer, you're assigning to the value that the pointer points to:

```
*str = *envp++;
```

The `*` before `str` causes the pointer to be dereferenced. Instead, you probably want:

```
str = *envp++;
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend. a question, When I said str = * envp ++ in the part of * envp ++ I'm also dereferencing? That is, what you are doing is actually saying

Str = * envp
And then say envp ++;

Comment: Yes, `*envp++` dereferences `envp`, but `envp` is of type `char**`, so you need to dereference if you want the `char*` value that it points to.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem with this `*str = *envp++;` is that you are referencing the str pointer and then assigning a pointer to a char. In other words:

> str is a pointer to a char
>
> *envp is a pointer to a char

Thus

> str = *envp++

would be a correct statement since both are pointers to a char. But in the provided code you are doing the following:

> *str is a char
>
> *envp is a pointer to a char

This means that you are trying to assign a "pointer to a char" to a char. The types do not match.

So fix this by changing your code like this:

```
char *str;
const char *usuario= NULL;
while(*envp)
{
    str = *envp++;
    if(... `
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, to see if I understood, then when I say

Char * str = * envp ++, is called redeferencing.

And actually the compiler does is declare the variable char * str and then does the assignment
Str = * envp ++

and other thing, When I said str = * envp ++ in the part of * envp ++ I'm also dereferencing? That is, what you are doing is actually saying

Str = * envp
And then say envp ++;

Comment: Yes, when you say `char *str = *envp++`. Then the compiler creates a variable called `str`. The type of `str` is then a pointer to a `char` (`char*`). After that, the `envp` is dereferenced (`*envp`). and then incremented once (`*envp++`). This value is then assigned to `str` (not `*str`). In this context the `*` in `char *str` is not the same as the `*` in `*envp++`. In the first case, the `*` means "pointer to" and in the second it means "dereference". Understanding pointers are hard, so read up on a bit more and you'll understand it eventually.

Comment: Ooooh, thank you again, the last question and I stop bothering :B, in the code `const char * user = NULL;` there is also dereferencing right?, In reality it says that the memory address is NULL.
Example `const char * user;` and more below initialize `user = NULL;`

And lastly, is there a C book that you recommend where all this comes from? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @EmiliOrtega No that is not dereferencing. I just made a blog post about this on my website specially for you, check it out here: [http://codehaven.co.za/blog/blogpost/?bid=9](http://codehaven.co.za/blog/blogpost/?bid=9). I apologise for the delay, I went to bed after you sent that previous message. Also, the blog post was written very swiftly, let me know if I made any obvious mistakes.

Comment: Don't worry , Thanks for answering :D but i have a question. In the code `char *str = *envp++` I think what the program is actually doing is first assigning the value of `* envp` to `stdr` and then increasing it once. But from what you tell me, it is increasing and then once increased it is assigned to "stdr", I wait your answer to see if I am correct or you.

Thanks :)

BTW your blog is really good !

Comment: @EmiliOrtega my apologies, you are correct. Since we see the "post increment operator" the old value (ie the value before the environment is incremented) will be assigned to str.